# What is wrong with my Fortigate LNS IP scheme configuration?

Tags: vpn, fortigate, l2tp

I'm trying to set up a VPN connection for a client-to-site scheme with  a fortigate VM applicance. This is for testing puropose so all clients and the fortigate are runned on VMWare.
Here is what I did so far :

- Client1 in LAN (Windows XP) : IP = 192.168.50.2
- Client2 outside (Windows XP) : IP = 196.47.60.1 (to simulate a public IP address)
- LNS (L2TP Network Server) : Fortigate

  - 2 ports : port1(LAN) with IP = 192.168.50.2 and port2(WAN) with IP = 196.47.60.2
  - One reserved range of IP that the VPN client will be given : 192.168.50.[50-60]. That reserved range is used cor the 'config vpn l2tp' sip and eip settings
  - One I have create an address object related to the devices VPN clients will be able to access in the LAN. Nothing more than 192.168.50/24
  - I created a firewall policy saying : incoming interface (port1) with IP range 192.168.50[50-60] -> outgoing interface (port2) with IP 192.168.50/24

Brief I followed the tutorial here

http://docs-legacy.fortinet.com/fos50hlp/50/index.html#page/FortiOS%205.0%20Help/PPTP_L2TP.104.15.html

In the client2, I created a VPN connection. I want the target IP to be 192.168.50.2 but it doesnt work. Though I am able to bing port2 of the fortigate from my client. When I change the target address to 196.47.50.1, it does not work either.

What did I do wrong ? I hope I won't need to post MY WHOLE CONFIG here....

NB : Please I don't want to use forticlient ; only